# Prove that $B = f(A)$ is symmetric, where A is a symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

For a function defined as $B = f(A)$ where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Prove that B is also symmetric.
There are no constraints on f and it can be any function.

Comment: Any polynomial of symmetric matrix is symmetric.. but function is a construct more general...

Comment: "For a function defined as $B=f(A)$..." I cannot discern any definition of a function in this.

Comment: You must say more clearly what you mean by a function. As Widawensen said correctly, a polynomial of symemtric matrices is symmetric, so if $f$ can be written as a power series, this is easy to prove. But assume $f$ is a function on matrices that switches, for example, the first and the second column, then it will destroy the symmetry.

Comment: Let $B_0$ be any non-symmetric matrix. Define a function by setting $f(A) := B_0$ for every $A$. This is a valid function where, even for symmetric $A$, the value $f(A)$ is not symmetric. Therefore, I assume that  you didn't completely understand the question and you might want to re-check.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true though.

Define $f(X) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, it's not symmetric for any $X$, even symmetric ones.